# Qt: How to check if the entered Primary-key exist in SQLite database or not?

Tags: database, qt, sqlite, primary-key

I am trying to check if the primary-key (entered manually by the user) exists already in the SQLite database or not (in order to decide whether to proceed with an insertion of a new record or to do an update for an existent one).

I've tried:

- `query.exce();`
- `query.isEmpty();`
- and bellow I'm trying: `guery.isNull();`

However, they all give me the same result: they all say the record doesn't exist (return 0) and go to the insertion function. They return 0 even if the ref_no does exist).

Here is my code for `isNull()` function:

```
int DatabaseManager::checkRefNoExist(QString ref_no){
    QSqlQuery query;
    query.prepare("SELECT * FROM basic_info WHERE ref_no = :ref_no");
    query.bindValue(":ref_no", ref_no);
    query.exec();

    if(query.isNull(ref_no.toInt())){
        return 0; // whatever the ref_no is, it always comes here !!
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `ref_no.toInt()` as column index. This does not make sense.

To check whether the query returned any result row, try to fetch the first result (with `query.first()` or `query.next()`).

Comment: I have to specify the `ref_no` for the query to fetch the value. The `ref_no` is passed to this function as QString value which I need to converted to `int` using the `ref_no.toInt()` function.